# Image deformations in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

Tensorflow 1.8 added utilities to *apply* deformations to images (see e.g. [sparse_image_warp](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/sparse_image_warp) and [dense_image_warp](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/dense_image_warp)). This is great, but I've been unable to find any utilities to *create* the deformations.

As an example, I can randomly rotate an image according to:

```
radians = tf.random_uniform([], -1.0, 1.0)
img = tf.contrib.image.rotate(img, radians)
```

What would the equivalent code be to deform an image?

```
flow = ...  # your code here
img = tf.contrib.image.dense_image_warp(img, flow)
```

I'm aware that the flow could be generated in several ways, and I'm not terribly picky about which one is chosen as long as it does not rip the image appart (e.g. I'm looking for a [diffeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism) or at least a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)).

Comment: I think I saw some code that could be relevant in Keras data augmentation queues code but I could be mistaken.

Comment: image.apply_affine_transform ?

Comment: `apply_affine_transform`, as the name implies, _applies_ a deformation, it does not _generate_ it. And while affine transforms are diffeomorphisms, they are perhaps a bit too simple.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you meant by generating

Comment: A combination of np.meshgrid+addition of a random generated vector reshaped to fit the meshgrid ?

Comment: That only works for very small deformations. If they are larger than 1 pixel you might end up ripping the image apart, so to say.

Comment: Hmm okay interesting

Answer (score 3):

It seems you might want to look at [this kaggle page](https://www.kaggle.com/bguberfain/elastic-transform-for-data-augmentation) on elastic transformations, which implements [this article](http://cognitivemedium.com/assets/rmnist/Simard.pdf).

This is quite similar to my meshgrid+noise baseline although it seems to be done with more care, the examples presented show that you can perturb the image greatly without getting complete garbage, hope it helps.

**EDIT:** You can take a look at [this new library](https://github.com/albu/albumentations) that implements different image transformations including Grid distortion, which might provide an alternative to elastic transform for image warping

Comment: This code doesn't use tensorflow layers as in question.

Comment: Use `tf.py_func`or reimplement it using the corresponding functions it is straightforward.

Comment: As I understand the question is to how to use `tf.contrib.image.dense_image_warp`.

Comment: You just compute the offsets in numpy using my answer then you convert it to a tensor using `tf.convert_to_tensor()`and you have your flow argument for the `dense_image_wrap()`.